# Visual Studio 2010 reporting design query

Tags: visual-studio-2010, report

It is to my understanding that in previous version of visual studio you could create a table that had toggles, when the toggles were hidden the table would display neatly where there would be no "gaps" where the data was hidden

However so far in 2010 version I'm using when the toggles are hidden there is still "gaps" where the data is there but just not visible, here is a screenshot to demonstrate what I mean

[image: Notice where in the first image the 2nd row has space for two gaps]

Notice where in the first image the 2nd row has space for two gaps

Is there a way of removing these gaps so that the table is better presented?

Answer (score 0):

Hi managed to figure it out, what was needed was to select the row visibility, and select it so that it can be toggled via an expression of my Issue Type Field. I then set the visibility of the row to hidden. When this was done it looked like the first table in the picture below, then when the toggles are clicked it will look like the second table

[image: Demo Tables]